# Javascript: Find product of adjacent array elements and returning largest product

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, ecmascript-6, iteration

I'm working on sharpening my JS skills and working through some problems on CodeSignal. I'm working on the following problem:

***Given an array of integers, find the pair of adjacent elements that has the largest product and return that product.***

So for example, given the array `[2,3,5,10,2,4]` I would want to do the following:

```
2 * 3 = 6
5 * 10 = 50
2 * 4 = 8
```

Then I want to return the largest product, in this case 50.

My approach is to iterate with a for loop, multiply i * i + 1, push the product into a new array, then increment the for loop by 2 so I can multiple the next two numbers in the array. When I'm done pushing into the new array I want to use `Math.max` and call it on the array of numbers to return the largest product.

`Math.max` does not work on arrays so I will use the ES6 spread operator and do something like this: 
`Math.max(...products);`

Here's what I have so far that isn't working:

```
function adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) {
    var products = [];
    for(var i = 0; i <= inputArray.length; i = i + 2) {
        products.push(inputArray[i] * inputArray[i + 1]);

    };

     // Correctly logs elements of products array
     console.log(products);

     // NaN error
     console.log(Math.max(...products));

     return Math.max(...products);

}
```

Does this NaN error have to do with attempting to call Math.max and the spread operator before the for loop finishes and has the values pushed into the array?

Comment: Look at the `products` closely, it's not only the expected numbers. Your loop condition is off, it should be `i < inputArray.length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're adding 2 to `i` and then looking at `i` and `i + 1`, you really only want to be looping between `0` and `inputArray.length - 2`.

Given your example code you can fix this by changing the `for` loop such that:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= inputArray.length - 2; i = i + 2) {
        products.push(inputArray[i] * inputArray[i + 1]);

};
```

Let's break that down manually so you can see it in action:

- `i = 0` and our values are `[2, 3]` who's product is `6`
- `i = 2` and our values are `[5, 10]` who's product is `50`
- `i = 4` and our values are `[2, 4]` who's product is `8`.

At this point our loop ends because `inputArray.length - 2` is also equal to `4` i.e. `6 - 2 === 4`.

You may also want to include a check for uneven arrays so that you don't end up with the product of `n` and  `undefined`. You could do that by checking the values before you find their product  and ignoring any `undefined` containing pairs.

For some extra fun, here's a recursive version of the function:

```
const adjacentElementsProduct = ([a, b, ...rest], agg = []) =>  rest.length 
? adjacentElementsProduct(rest, [...agg, a * b]) 
: Math.max(...agg);
```

Answer (score 1):

`i <= inputArray.length` should be `i < inputArray.length`. Array indexes go from `0` to `array.length-1`. When `i == inputArray.length`, you're adding two `undefined` values, which produces `NaN`.

Comment: `i < inputArray.length` would be fine if the array is guaranteed to be of even length.

Answer (score -1):

this is another method by using map function..

```
function adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) {
    let n;
    return inputArray.map(n=>(n*(n+1)));
}
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
console.log("The arrays after multiplication of adjacent numbers");
const result=adjacentElementsProduct(numbers);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).